# how to convert Text box to text area

Tags: php, html

I feel certain this is an easy fix for the people here however I'm racking my brain as where I'm messing this up. Right now, this is echo'd as a simple text line box. However I want to change it to a TextArea so that I can have multiple lines. This is on an edit entry page I'm working on. Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated.
What I've already tried: Searching the internet for examples, re-arranging the tags for text area, and thats all I currently know to do. I couldn't not find any solutions online to fix it.

Edit: Yes there is a mix of html and php in this. This will currently display the database result in a text field. I am only trying to change it to a textarea to have multiple lines.

Many thanks

```
    <label for="user_review">Review </label> 
    <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="user_review" 
            value="'.$row["user_review"].'" name="user_review" 
            cols="30" rows="5">
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group"></div>
</textarea>
<br>
```

Comment: Typo?  You're trying to open an `<input>` element and trying to close a `</textarea>` element.  It's one or the other.  (You also have a closing `</div>` that doesn't match anything and should be removed.)

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of errors but input with type textare does not exists. Use the textarea tag. You have only a closing textarea tag:

```js
<label for="user_review">Review </label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="user_review" name="user_review" cols="30" rows="5">
{{ $row["user_review"] }}
</textarea>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like they're using Blade at all, so `{{ }}` will not work

Comment: Between this, and @riggsfolly I learned a lot. I can see that the value has to go between the actual tags. This one doesn't display what is in that row though. It shows {{ $row["user_review"] }} instead

Comment: I got it. I replaced the {{ }} with ' ' and it works! I couldn't have even figured out that much without all your help. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution thanks to everyones help in here and my edit

```
<label for="user_review">Review </label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="user_review" name="user_review" cols="30" rows="5">
'.$row["user_review"].'
</textarea><div class="form-group"><br>
```